# Can I name a male character Artemis?

Tags: characters, naming, gender

So I'm writing a story and there is a character that is a male that I want to name Artemis. The reason, simply put, is that he has a sister with a name I really like that is TECHNICALLY a boy's name (the nickname however is sweet sounding and was the reason I chose the full name).

I wanted to go for a 'OMG, your brother has a girl's name and you have a boy's name' but I'm worried about using it because it isn't a common boy's name at all. In fact the only male called Artemis I've ever heard of is Artemis Fowl (Who is nothing like my character other than the fact that they'd have the same first name).

Is it alright for me to use it?

Comment: If it worked for Colfer (Artemis Fowl) why wouldn't it work for you? You can name your character Buhubu if it serves your story and doesn't alienate your reader.

Comment: Another very famous Artemis is Artemis Entreri from the Forgotten Realms. He's an assassin and the arch-nemesis of Drizzt Do'Urden.

Comment: One of Johnny Cash's most famous song is "A Boy Named Sue."

Comment: And in the real world strange names abound. Don't forget the Zappa girl's feminine name, "Moon Unit."

Comment: Another not-very famous Artemis was Artemis Gordon, who was James West's sidekick on Wild Wild West

Comment: Also note that Sailor Moon has a male cat named Artemis.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin That's Sailor Venus' cat. Sailor Moon's is called Luna and is female.

Comment: I meant the show. :)

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can use Artemis; it is from Greek mythology and impossible to copyright as a name. The Greek for the male versions of this name are Artemas and Artemus, both are listed in The Character Naming Sourcebook (and mean "gift of Artemis"). You violate nothing by using a name already in the public domain.

I would avoid using the full name of a fictional character; Don't call a character "Clark Kent" or "Bruce Wayne" or "Harry Potter". The copyright owners of those characters might be able to claim damages if the name of your character helps you succeed commercially. But that is a combination: One cannot copyright "Clark", "Bruce", or "Harry", and cannot copyright the surnames "Kent", "Wayne", or "Potter", none of them are original combinations of letters used as names.

Answer (score 11):

It’s your story. You are free do whatever you’d like with names. I would say many readers, but not most, will be aware of the mythological twins Artemis and Apollo, and among those readers you will produce your intended shock factor.

Answer (score 8):

You can name a male character "Sally" and a female character "Bruno" if you want to. It's not like there's a law against it.

But the question to ask yourself is not,  "Am I allowed to do this?" but "Is it a good idea to do this?"

If there is some reason why this name is significant and the story won't work if the character has some other name, then of course do it.

But if it's just a matter of, "oh, this name popped into my head and I kind of like it", I'd say probably don't. Giving a male character a girl's name will be distracting to the reader. Readers may be confused if this character is a guy or a girl, or if this is the name of the guy-character or of some other girl-character. If no one in the story ever notices or comments on the odd name, it may seem unrealistic. Like if I knew a man named Sally in real life, I would be very surprised if he did NOT get jokes about his name and people being confused by it.

Answer (score 7):

It's not so uncommon for boys to have girl names and otherwise. As example I can give the example name "Kim". It can be both: A boys name, a girls name, a short form from "Kimberly".

It is completely up to you if the name matches or not. From my opinion Artemis is not a name that sounds like boy or girl and can match both

Comment: Actually, it is uncommon. There are a few names in English speaking cultures which are not bound to one gender, and it is a much more frequent occurence for a male name to become neutral or female over time than the other way round (or maybe there are even no examples for the other way round, I forget the details of the research I have read). Also, unusual names like "Navy" are used much more for girls than for boys. And it is more socially accepted to use "true" boy names for girls than the other way round. On the whole, parents and society are much more conservative with boy names. Of course

Comment: this is a descriptive summary of trends which are commonly observed, not a prescriptive set of rules for writers. But my point is that your answer is a bit too superficial (mixing up the cases of gender neutral names and gendered names given to the opposite gender) and misses important trends. The OP can still name the boy Artemis - here, it is actually helpful that it is not a common name in English. But not because it is "not so uncommon".

Comment: One of the more Bizzare unisex names is Ashley, which is often assumed to be a girl's name only but is seeing a small resurgence in boy's names as it's becoming common knowledge that Ashley was a boy's name in it's beginnings.  The most famous male Ashley I know of was from "Gone with the Wind", but the tv how "Castle" used a male Ashley for the teenage daughters' boyfriend and she went out of the way to avoid pronouns so her father would assume she was spending time with a female friend and not a boyfriend.

Comment: @hszmv If something you specifically want to do in the story is have there be confusion about whether a certain person is male or female, then sure, giving them a name that is routinely used for both, like Ashley or Terry or Francis, is a good idea. But unless you really want there to be such confusion, I'd say don't do it, because it is going to create confusion. It's find to break conventions when you have a purpose in doing so. But don't break conventions just because you feel like it or for no particular reason.

Comment: @Jay:  I had a character who I knew through his mannerisms would be suspected as being gay, but when writing I was not committed to saying that he was either gay or straight but flamboyant.  He was however, never going to be a romantic partner to my female lead, but was comfortable enough to discuss his numerous dates with her.   More as a troll move to people curious about his sexuality, I decided that all his romantic partners had unisex names so the reader couldn't be sure from a name drop if the date the character was dating even a single gender exclusively.

Comment: @hszmv Fair enough: You are deliberately trying to preserve ambiguity, so yes, given that goal, it makes sense to use ambiguous names. Whether this plot device added to the story I can't say, as I haven't read the story. :-)

Answer (score 3):

There is no law against it, but I would discourage it. Personally, I would find that particular quirk distracting and immersion breaking. Unless the fact that this character has a feminine name is very important to the story, I don't think it's worth it.

This is actually one of the reasons I wasn't able to get into Artemis Fowl.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was of the Johnny Cash song "A boy named Sue", and it sounds like you're already thinking of an interesting back story. There's also a nice opportunity to refer to him by a shortened version in earlier chapters and go for a dramatic revelation of the full name.

But the short answer here is that you're the writer and as long as you do it well, you can do anything you like.

Anything at all.

[Twitches cape over shoulder and walks away into the night with an indulgent but slightly disturbing chuckle.]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of Artemis in ancient greek being used as a male name, but, for what it's worth, in modern greek Άρτεμις is the female name (same name as the godess) but there exists a male version too, which is Αρτέμης. Note the accents: in the female version, the stress is on the initial A, whereas in the male version it's the second vowel, the e, that is stressed*. The different spelling of the last vowel is just historical spelling with no impact on pronunciation. (transliterating: Α->A, ρ->r, τ->t, ε->e, μ->m, ι->i, η->i, ς->s)

My impression is that, while the female version of the name is the more popular of the two, the male version isn't too rare, either.

*Modern greek does not have short and long vowels--they are all short. But each word has one syllable that is stressed, i.e. louder than the others (of course, the cadence of sentences complicates how words sound in natural speech, but that's the basic theory anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Go for it! It is not that uncommon for males to be called Artemis. Besides, I have always found it strange that humans made a different set of names for both halves of humanity.

(By the way: may I read your story? It looks pretty awesome :D)

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE. Please take a look at our [tour] and [help] pages, they're great for figuring out how our site works.

Comment: You may find it strange that human beings have different sets of names for males and females, but 95+% of humanity think this is normal and routine. If you want to write a story that pointedly says that you think this is silly, sure. But if you just throw cross-gender names into a "conventional" story, almost all readers will find this confusing and distracting. Even readers who agree with you that we shouldn't distinguish such names know that in fact we do, and so will find this confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I am just reading a book A Winter Journey by the critically acclaimed Amelie Nothomb (~110 pages, definitely worthwile read! Great language, interesting plot), which does something very similar. Even with the greek references.
The main character is called Zoïle (which is based on the greek philosopher Zoilus, with which the main character is not happy, since Zoilus was considered a very cynic small mind and his parents actually wanted a girl, which they could call Zoe to rhyme with their first daughter Chloe) and the target of his affection is called Astrolabe, which I think was based on the writer Astralabius.

So yeah, you can do that, get away with it and even make it an essential part of your story, since this is something the main characters bond over in the aforementioned "A winter journey".